# Android Gradle Build take 40mins

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, apple-m1

my mac pro is M1 and RAM is 16G, Android Studio version is

```
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7678000, built on August 27, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 11.4
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 3072M
Cores: 8
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: Dart, io.flutter, wu.seal.tool.jsontokotlin
```

someone can tell me why? Every time I sync gradle it takes almost 40mins, make me sick.....

[image]

my unityLibrary module's gradle like follow:
[image]

and my dependences:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Android studio doesn't support arm based processor officially yet, So that might be causing an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using MacBook M1 Pro 16GB ram variant. For me it usually completes around 5 mins. I'm using this version of Android studio `Android Studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1) Patch 3`. Please install the same and try.

Also Gradle builds can take longer time because of slower internet connection. Kindly check the same too.

Answer (score 0):

One cannot mix Android Support with AndroidX Libraries, while for an low-power ARM CPU, this might be "normal" (also on PC notebooks, the performance is sub-optimal, compared to a desktop machine). In order to reduce the build time by +/- 50%, fully migrate to AndroidX and then disable the Jetifier (which is a quite time-consuming Gradle task).

Answer (score 0):

I have also a M1 with 16G and for faster build time you can use [Azul JDK](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?version=java-8-lts&os=macos&architecture=arm-64-bit&package=jdk).
You can find a very nice Medium tutorial [here](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/speed-up-android-compilation-in-apple-m1-device-6dbca65b4bb9).

Before this I needed 7 minutes and a half to run all my tests and now with the Azul JDK only 1 minute and a half.

Hope you enjoy.